# How do I clone from GitLab?

Tags: git, gitlab, clone

When I try to clone a project from GitLab it says "Failed to authenticate".
I typed my username and password correctly(I've tried it few times), configured my SSH key.  I've tried my access token instead of my password and still unable to clone. I'm using HTTPS clone

Comment: Hello,
Which operating system do you use?
If windows, the issue might be that you have wrong credential saved on `Credential Manager`. Just wipe them out, ensure that you have correct credentials and pass them once again.

Comment: If you've configured SSH keys, please ensure that you have your private key in proper place in your home directory and clone project by using SSH instead HTTPS.

Comment: What was the issue?

Comment: As you suggested I've cloned it using SSH. The reason I was so hung-up using HTTPS was I could clone projects from github using HTTPS but unable to do it from gitlab. After many hours of trying I've used SSH. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you have configure your SSH key, make sure:

- said ssh key does authenticate your properly: `ssh -Tv git@gitlab.com`
- to use an SSH URL when cloning your GitLab repository

  ```
  git clone git@gitlab.com:me/myRepo
  ```

> configured my SSH key. I'm using HTTPS clone

Then the SSH key does not matter.

Check your `git config --global credential.helper`: if set, it might have cached the wrong credentials.

Answer (score 0):

Please create an access token from:

https://gitlab.com/-/profile/personal_access_tokens

Make sure to check all the required boxes, at least you should select `read_repository` and `write_repository`.

Next time when you clone the project, use your email and this access token rather than your password.

Comment: Thank for your response. I've tried this but still unable to clone it.

Comment: Could you please share more detail about the issue?
What tool are you using? ex: VScode or terminal.
What is your OS?